# Yii2 Controller Firing Twice / Depending on browser

Tags: controller, yii2

The controller/action is firing twice in some/most browsers.

Yii2

Firefox 91.0 (64-bit)

First test, keep dev console closed.

SiteController

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $path = \Yii::getAlias('@console') . '/runtime/';
    $n = 'A__' . self::random_uppercase(2);
    file_put_contents($path . $n . '.txt', time());

    return $this->render('test'); // Blank page is fine
}


private function random_uppercase($n = 1)
{
    $out = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $out .= chr(rand(65, 90));
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Run page in Firefox

console/runtime

```
> A__KW.txt
```

(delete file)

Open developer console and refresh the page

console/runtime

```
> A__XY.txt
> A__JU.txt
```

Action fires twice.

---

Chrome
-- Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)

It happen regardless if the dev console is open or not.

Action fires twice.

---

Opera
-- Version:78.0.4093.147

It happen regardless if the dev console is open or not.

Action fires twice.

---

Can anyone reproduce the results?

I tried this on a couple of my sites and the results where the same for me.

Has anyone found a way to limit to only one call?

It's messing up my $_SESSION values

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help others.

It's subtle so if you are not looking for it probably goes unnoticed.
( at least on my sites )

The first call is from the page/action (/?r=site/test)
This routes correctly.

The second one is from actionIndex in that controller.

The fix for me is to not use actionIndex and then no further action happens.

.

I had the test code snippet in actionIndex so it was not being noticed until I changed the file names. Then I could see that it was page route and then index.

If this is not clear enough, post your question and I will try and answer it.